# JPG previews too large

Tags: mac, macos

I am facing a problem with the preview of the images in the ‘Place’ dialogue box of JPG images exported from Adobe Illustrator CS6. What happens is that the preview image is huge and it’s off the screen. I uploaded an image so you can see what I mean.

[image: Place dialogue box preview]

Comment: This (to me) appears to be a MacOS issue, and *not* an Illustrator issue. I see it at times and just resize the window. For some reason the MacOS makes that preview pane huge on occasion. It's not Illustrator.

Comment: I did resize the window and changed the preview mode several times. However, the problem remains. The only solution is to place the images by dragging them from the finder, but this is not practical when you need to replace an existing image inside Illustrator. Thank you anyway Scottt.

Comment: I use XtraFinder. Can this cause a preview conflict?